# Creating and Populating Values to Variable Variables

Tags: php, variables

I've done this before without problems but now can't seem to get it to work. From an array, I want to create variables of the values and then to populate any that have been submitted by a form or assign an empty value to them if they have not been submitted.

The $Fields array, which contains database column names and is generated automatically from a query, is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID
    [1] => Name
    [2] => EMail
    [3] => Message
    [4] => Site
)
```

and the PHP code is:

```
// Create variables from table columns and populate on post
foreach ($Fields as $key => $val) :
    if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST[$val])) :
        $$key = $val;
        $val = $_POST[$val];
    else :
        $$key = $val;
        $val = "";
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: In your foreach loop, $key is a number. You can't make a variable name out of that.

Comment: I thought as much but replacing $$keys with $$val still gives errors that variables used elsewhere are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With miken32's assistance, it is now working and greatly simplified over my original long-winded code:

```
// Create variables from table columns and populate on post
foreach ($Fields as $val) :
        $$val = (isset($_POST[$val])) ?  $_POST[$val]  : "";
endforeach;
```

This will create variables from the array of column names and when the form is submitted to itself it will pick up the post values to keep the fields populated as long as the form fields have names that match the column names..

Comment: The null coalesce operator that I included in my answer does exactly what your `isset()` stuff does, and there's no point in pulling `$key` into the loop if you're not using it.

Comment: Thank you, I removed $key from my development copy here but just removed it from the code above too. On the null coalesce operator, I don't see it but I tried to use code that more closely matched my usual "style" of code writing. As for variable variables, I'm surprised that they are not used more although I imagine there could be some security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're doing is trying to set some variables based on the values of selected `$_POST` elements, with an empty default, just do this:

```
$fields = ["ID", "Name", "Email", "Message", "Site"];
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $$field = $_POST[$field] ?? "";
}
```

But variable variables are not something used a lot; better to just stick with calling them from the array. It makes your code more clear as to where the values are coming from. To set defaults, you can use `array_merge()` on an empty array:

```
$fields = ["ID" => "", "Name" => "", "Email" => "", "Message" => "", "Site" => ""];
$posts = array_merge($fields, $_POST);
```

Comment: Thank you for the assist. Just to clarify, the array is coming from a query of the table's columns, not from a post so it's structure will always be key=>value but I want any post to populate the values that might be submitted. The form is always submitting using the actual column names.

Comment: I'm not following you. If this code isn't doing what you want, try editing the question to make your problem more clear.

Comment: "The form is always submitting using the actual column names" was perhaps not too clear. What I meant was that the form already has field names that match the database's column names.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should stick to using the arrays and not creating variable variables, but since you're doing it anyway and you know which ones you need; you can change `$Fields`:

```
$Fields = array("ID"=>"", "Name"=>"", "Email"=>"", "Message"=>"", "Site"=>"");
```

Then just add the arrays and extract:

```
extract($_POST + $Fields);
```

Comment: Thank you but I don’t know the ones I need in advance, which is the point of doing it this way. $Fields comes from a query of the various tables and provides the array but I hard-coded it in my original question as an example of the array structure. Anyway, it is working perfectly now.

Comment: Ok then `array_flip($Fields)`, simple enough.